# Is it possible to redirect URLs in apache based on query parameters without RewriteEngine?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, apache2

We use Apache HTTPD server version 2.2
I need to redirect URLs in apache based on query parameters.
Is it possible to redirect URLs without RewriteEngine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can try mod_alias which has a number of directives which can redirect URLs in Apache:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Thanks, we use Apache HTTPD server version 2.2. I started to try to use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch.

Comment: asked additional question. May be you can help: http://serverfault.com/questions/828956/what-wrong-with-redirectmatch-of-apache-2-2-mod-alias