# What wrong with RedirectMatch of Apache 2.2 mod_alias?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, mod-alias

We use Apache HTTPD server version 2.2.
I try to use RedirectMatch of Apache 2.2 mod_alias without success ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

I need to create rule that will redirect only URLs whit parameters `change_url=1` for example

```
https://<IP>/servlet1?id=1&type=2&change_url=1
```

I have tried to use the following rule:

```
RedirectMatch (.*)change_url=1(.*) /keepurlprocess/$1
```

Unfortunately it does not work with required URL only when the `change_url` in the URL:

```
https://<IP>/change_url=1
```

What wrong in my regular expression?
How can apply it to query parameters?
In addition, I have some specific parameter `type`. For some types I do not need to perform redirect:

```
https://<IP>/servlet1?id=1&type=do_not_redirect&change_url=1
```

Is it possible to create rule like below?

```
RedirectMatch (.*)(change_url=1 AND NOT type=do_not_redirect)(.*)  /keepurlprocess/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. You should be able to drop a redirect in an IF statement

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Comment: We use 2.2. Do you have idea how to solve it in 2.2?

Comment: Why answer a question tagged `apache-2.2` with 2.4 docs?